# Convolution: graphing output y(t) with given input x(t) and impulse response h(t)

Tags: convolution, impulse-response

I have the following question in my mock exam.

[image]

My graphing looks as following:

[image]

Could someone please correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gunners You can work your problem in two parts. The first part is: the output with just the single +2 impulse input that occurs at time = 0 seconds. The second part is: the output with just the single -1 impulse input that occurs at time = 1 second. Your final answer is the sum of those two outputs.